# How can I add my own button in slack chat box by slack API

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to develop an APP and integrate it with Slack.

I have a confusion, can I add the app into chat box just like DropBox did? I searched the Slack API and found nothing about it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKy0P.png)

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know this feature is not available to Slack developers at the moment. Might be added at a later time though.

You could use a [slash command](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) instead to trigger your external application.